# Pass string from a console input to a tcp socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, java.util.scanner

I have a piece of software that can execute an external application and i am trying to use this to create a man in the middle to communicate with a separate system.

To execute the software i was going to give the path c:\TCPClient.jar  /"Alarm created"

What i want to do is pass the argument from the cmd line argument to the socket. so C:\TCPClient.jar /"send this string" would pass the argument to the output stream and send it to the socket.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
public class TCPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Socket tcpSocket = null;  
    DataOutputStream os = null;


    try {
        tcpSocket = new Socket("10.0.10.1", 445);
        os = new DataOutputStream(tcpSocket.getOutputStream());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Hostname not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldnt connect Check Listening port");
    }

if (tcpSocket != null && os != null) {
        try {
            String consoleInput;

           Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
           consoleInput = scanIn.nextLine();

           scanIn.close();            

    os.writeBytes(consoleInput);    



   os.close();


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }
}           
}
```

Comment: check that `if (tcpSocket != null && os != null) {`

Comment: Sorry my question isnt very clear.  What i want to do is pass the argument from the cmd to the socket. so C:\TCPClient.jar /"send this string" would pass the argument to the output stream and send it to the socket.

The actual socket functionality is working ok

Comment: what happens if you pass it a normal String e.g. HelloWorld!!

Comment: so maybe it is your `slash`, try `slashslash`

Comment: It will be in your `String[] args` why don't you work with that?

Comment: @Flikk Sorry i am a beginner here, Can you give me an example?  The string will change every time. Do i need to configure arguments in the project or anything?  I can see when i run it the connection opens and closes almost immediately.

Comment: @DisplayName try looking into that array and i'm sure you'll figure it out: `for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { System.out.println("Element " + i + ": " + args[i]);}` It's a simple array that contains all arguments you give to the program. It is defined in the head of your `main(String[] args)` will be back in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a program with an argument on the command line, for example `c:\TCPClient.jar "Alarm created"`, then the arguments will be passed to your java program in the main(`String[] args`) parameter.

You can write it to the DataOutputStream as

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    os.writeBytes(args[0]);
}
```